# Setting the Alarm at specific time of the day

Tags: android

I'am trying to set my alarm at certain time of the day e.g: 20:15
and this is the code that i'm working with but it doesn't go off at 20:15

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(AlarmActivity.this, MyBroadcastReceiver.class);
        intent.putExtra("Hekma", "One better than none");
        PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getService(AlarmActivity.this, 0,intent, 0);
        AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();



        cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 20);
        cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 15);
        cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
        alarm.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), pintent);
```

Answer (score 6):

I use `AlarmManager` in my project and it works perfectly. Try this it may help you:

```
Intent myIntent =  new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyAlarmService.class);
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(MainActivity.this, 0, myIntent, 0);
AlarmManager alarmManager =  (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 23);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 59);
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

Comment: this is static ,Alarm start on Date Picker date and time

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
alarm.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis() - System.currentTimeMillis(), pintent);
```

This should get the difference between the two times and therefore how long to go before when you want it to go off. Hence, it should go off at the time you want it to go off.

Comment: Ok, just comparing that again to my code I have for an alarm. The only other difference that I can see is that you have "PendingIntent.getService(....;". However, I have "PendingIntent.getBroadcast(....". put the arguments for alarm.set back to what you had and let me know if it works.

Comment: now it goes immediately regardless of the time i set after changing to PendingIntent.getBroadcast(...

Comment: it works now i removed (- System.currentTimeMillis()) thanks alot