# set multiple Alarms at different times

Tags: java, android

i have 3 times

- **02:00 AM**
- **02:30 AM**
- **08:15 PM**

i need set alarms for these times, and when the any time is coming
i need my app run sound from raw folder and show X layout

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set android alarm clock programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13909040/set-android-alarm-clock-programmatically)

Comment: well,, i don't need this (TimePickerDialog) i need put time as String and i need multi times not one time

Comment: You need to convert time in string to long to set the alarm. Whether you get that time from TimePicker or use your own hadrcoded string.

Comment: well,, just answear me how can i put three times??

Comment: i don't need TimePacker and...Etc i just need alarm me for this three times 02:00 AM
02:30 AM
08:15 PM

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16095113/4406346 Put you times in array, and execute the code mentioned in the post in a loop 3 times by converting string time to Calendar time.

Comment: ok, sister fatima i have other request from you if you want help me about prayer app i need just edit 1 line in it

Comment: here is source code (  https://github.com/alphamu/PrayTime-Android    )  this have notifaction for ramadhan ok? the problem  when the notifaction time is coming he not run the sound in raw folder he run the default sound of device how can i fix this bugs